# Windows Server 2012 - Event Triggers Not Working Properly

Tags: windows-server-2012

I'm running Windows Server 2012 on my work's server and running the Windows Backup application daily. I want to receive email notifications notifying me of the success or failure of this backup and in researching how to achieve this, I figured one of the best ways is to set up two batch files which run BLAT.exe and generate the appropriate emails.

I have configured the success batch file to run on event ID 4 within the Microsoft Windows Backup/Operational log and the failure batch file to run on event IDs 5, 9, 17, 22, 49, 50, 52, 517, 518, 521, 527, 528, 544, 546, 561 and 564 within the Microsoft Windows Backups/Operational log.

If I run these batch files manually the emails are sent and received successfully.

But I am not receiving them automatically when triggered by the aforementioned events.

What's puzzling me is that the history tab of each triggered task shows them as having run successfully. I have checked my junk emails and they're not in there either.

Does anyone have suggestions or things I can check? Thanks.

Comment: You can attach an email task to the events in question without using an external batch file. Have you tried that?

Comment: That function is deprecated - it even says (deprecated) next to it, and no longer works, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Fully functional mate (at least with the "no destination folder avaiable" fail test)

So if you have that Blat solution working out, i'd say you're only missing setting a few events on your trigger list, ones that you can find in that list a provided earlier.

EDIT: oh and you're missing a few events: [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734488(v=ws.10).aspx) is a complete list of them.

I'm running into similar issue but instead of using blat i've used [SendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/)

I've also checked manually the Event Viewer and i'm able to intentionally cause an Event 546 by unplugging the network cable from the targeted NAS. Even though i can clearly see the event happened, the task triggered like yours but the email was never sent.

Difference is i didn't use the batch file, i instead call out the program sendemail.exe and proceed to add the parameters do actually send the email, also tryed the parameteres before hand on a console and the email goes with no problem.